# django db_index for foreign key reverse lookup

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I've read that django creates db_index automatically for all foreign keys. However, does that db_index improve the performance of the reverse lookup as well?

For example, if B has a foreign key to A and I use a.b_set.all(), do I enjoy the performance boost from the db index or not?

And if not, is there a way to make the foreign key reverse lookup faster with db index?

Thanks,

Comment: In short, yep is work. But if you have any performance issues you better post some code with more explanation on the concrete problem.

Comment: The foreign key points to a pk, so that is indexed already. The `db_index` on the ForeignKey field is for reverse lookups. So, to answer the question: yes.

Comment: Thanks. I'd post code but its not like we have a specific performance issue to solve, more like we're looking for ways to improve our models to boost up performance in general and I wanted to make sure we are not losing speed over silly reverse lookups that could have been better with just a simple change. Todor, C14L feel free to format a proper answer with source so I can pick it as the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say the you have a simple model structure:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

As you mention `Book.author` already have index, because it's a `ForeignKey`

Now querying:

```
author_books = Book.objects.filter(author=a)
```

or

```
author_books = a.book_set.all()
```

produce the exact same query, therefore the `book.author` index will be used in both situations.

Comment: Does this work for this query: `Book.objects.filter(author__name="John")`?

Comment: Not exactly, you need another index on the `author.name` field in order to find those authors called "John". After that the `FK` on books will be used to find their books.

Comment: Does this mean that if I set `name` as an index on the `Author` model, then `author__name="John"` will use that index? Because `author__name` isn't an option as an index on the `Book` model. What's odd is that, let's say `author.name` is a `unique` field. I would have thought that this means that an index on `Author.name` isn't all that useful. But an `Author` can have many `Book` objects, so the default index on the `Book.author_id` column makes a lot of sense...because `author_id` has many duplicates to index together. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Every `FK` is an index and will be used if you filter on it. The same is true for `unique` fields, so no need to add anything if its unique. The query you mention requires data from two tables, and the database will split it into two parts: 1) find all authors called john, if name is unique or there is an index on it, it will be used to find those authors, otherwise a full table scan will be made. 2) Now after you found all those authors, the database needs to find their books -> the index on `book.author` will be used for this second part of the query.